# C++ and the const reference to temporary binding issue (Implementing the D language pass by value and by reference rules in C++0X)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

I was wondering to what extend it's possible to mimic the D language rules for pass by value and pass by reference rules in C++. For background please see the following two references (mostly Alexandrescu):

http://bartoszmilewski.wordpress.com/category/d-programming-language/page/2/

and

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/msg/303e3bf2407a7609?

One of the key differences is that in D const references does not bind (as non const ones) to temporaries.

However, I am not aware of any way to define a generic class X in such a way that the following code will fail to compile:

```
void f(const X& x) {...}
f( X() ); //Cannot disable binding of const ref to X
```

One possibility could be to make f a template function, check rvalue/lvalue-ness of the argument passed (possible in C++0X) and use disable_if but this clutters the code too much and does not scale well.

Another possibility could be to introduce a template class like

```
template<class T> Ref<T> : public T {...} //D-style ref, does not bind to temporaries!
```

and then use

```
void f(Ref<const X> x) {...} //Does not look bad....
f( X() ); //Compile error here is doable, I checked a similar example already...
```

However, this way I loose the ability to write template functions taking Ref as the following will not compile...

```
template<class T> void ft(Ref<const T> x) {...}
ft( X() ); //Template deduction error
```

What are your thoughts? Any suggestion/comment/help is appreciated!

Comment: My thought: if you like D then use it!

Comment: I probably would, but practical considerations make this not an option at this time :)

Comment: interesting question. I'd really like to be able to disable this behavior too. It's created a number of bugs when references to those "bound" temporaries have been returned, and some of them cannot be detected by anything else than whole program analysis...

Answer (score 3):

Overload on rvalue reference:

```
void f(X&&); // undefined
void f(const X& x) {...}
f( X() ); // error: f(X&&) undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for the interesting suggestion! I would have hoped to stay with a single declarationn, as it's easy to forget the extra overloading...

Comment: Also, I think this will not work with function templates, as overloading say T& and T&& will cause ambiguity...

Comment: Instead of a linker error, you might also try `void f(X&&) = delete;` to get a compile-time error.

Comment: @UncleBens: good remark, C++0x is still too fresh for this to have kicked in.

Comment: This will not work with constant rvalues. You need a `const X&&` instead.